# How to move an image back and forth with javascript

Tags: 2d, javascript, html5, movement, html-canvas

I currently am trying to make a baseball game and have this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/769BK/ I have the `baseballX` set to a decrement, and then I try increasing the value using `baseballX++;` but it won't stop the `baseballX--;` after that so it stays in the same place. I need to somehow stop the `baseballX--;` and that way I can use `baseballX++;`

Thanks for any help at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never tell your script to stop incrementing the position of the baseball. To do this, have a boolean as a flag as to whether to increase the baseball or not. An example of this would be

```
var flag = true;

if (flag)
{
    //do something, and eventually set flag to false
    flag = false;
}

else
{
    //do something else
}
```

In this instance, you would stop incrementing when the flag is false, and begin incrementing then. I would read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630404/what-is-a-boolean-flag) question even though it is in VB because it will help you understand the concept behind this behavior.

**EDIT**

What I mean when you start/stop the increment, is when you are changing the position of the ball. I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/769BK/2/) showing what is happening. The main error you were getting was that you would move the baseballX back, then forward, then back, etc. I fixed this using the flag, and in your `throwBack` function, you reset `baseballX` to -350. Some pseudocode of what was happening is like:

```
while (true)
{
    pitch();//1st time: move the ball backwards; 2nd time: the ball's X is greater than -350, so move back until it is less
    if (ballX < -350)
    {
        throwBack();//1st time: resets the ball position to -350, and moves forward; 2nd time: the ball is below so move forward, rinse and repeat
    }
}
```

The flag enabled us to do

```
while (true)
{
    if (!baseballBack)
        pitch();//1st time: move the ball backwards; 2nd time: flag tells us to stop pitching
    if (ballX < -350 || baseballBack)
    {
        baseballBack = true;
        throwBack();//1st time: resets the ball position to -350, and moves forward; 2nd time: the flag is true, so continue to execute.
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly would I implement this? Could you demonstrate with a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com)? I'm not sure that you explained how to stop incrementing? You say here:`In this instance, you would stop incrementing when the flag is false, and begin incrementing then.` I don't believe you explain how to stop and start the increment?

Comment: @Geroy290 Check my edits, I explain what was happening and what is now happening, along with another fiddle

Comment: Is there a way I could stoop the ball from moving and then start it again?

Comment: @Geroy290 I would do the same thing you did earlier where you tested the ball's x position, except see if it is larger, then reset the flag... Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/769BK/4/) for a demonstration that looks like pong:)

Comment: Is it possible to make it with a timer of sorts so that it would be caught and then thrown back a couple of seconds later?

Comment: @Geroy290 Yes, [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/769BK/5/), but I would start trying new things, and asking new questions based off of your new problems. This makes use of the amount of milliseconds passed since the start time, and until it is greater than 3000 (3 sec) then it does nothing. There is probably a more efficient way to do this though

Comment: Alright thank you! I found out I could do this with the `setTimeout` method that JS provides, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do like so:

```
var baseballMoveBack = true;  

function toggleMovement() {
    if (baseballMoveBack) baseballMoveBack = false;
    else baseballMoveBack = true;
}

function loop() {
    if (baseballMoveBack) baseballX--;
    else baseballX++;

    setTimeout(loop, 1);
}
```

First declaring a variable that tells us whether the ball should go back or forth. 
Then we make a function that will toggle the `baseballMoveBack` boolean. Last we have a loop that will increase or decrease `baseballX`.

Hope this helps!